# how to get the directory of the file contain a specified function in python

Tags: python

I have 3 file main.py, a.py, b.py and a function `func()` belongs to either a.py or b.py but I don't know exactly which. The code in the main.py:

```
from a import *
from b import *
func()
```

I want to get the directory of the file containing the func(), here is a.py or b.py. So how can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: comment out `from a import *` and rerun.  if you get an undefined error, it came from a, if you don't, it came from b.  The second import overrides the first.

Comment: @RufusVS nice answer hahaha

Comment: `func.__module__` is the module object in which the function was defined. You can then ask the object for its name or path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to get file paths of modules containing the desired functions:

```
file_path = func.__code__.co_filename
dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path) # since you wanted directory
```

where `func` is the function you imported from one of the modules.

Note: This will work for all function objects that are instances of the python `function` class. For eg, this won't work for functions in numpy, because they are instances of the `numpy.ufunc` class.

Answer (score 2):

This is why they tell you not to do `import *`. As a rule of thumb, import only the names you need from any given import, to avoid confusion of this nature.

What you can do is check, in reverse order, which module contains the function you're concerned about. Later imports should overwrite earlier ones with the same name.

```
if hasattr(b, 'func') and b.func is func:
    print(b.__file__)
elif hasattr(a, 'func') and a.func is func:
    print(a.__file__)
else:
    print("func came from somewhere else")
```

Comment: I tried it but I get the error ```File "d:\python\cc\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    if hasattr(b, 'func') and b.func is func:
NameError: name 'b' is not defined``` . Morever, I searched for the the hasattr() and seem it just work for class and attribute of that class. I missed something, didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

You can just look, by listing all the functions in a module with:

```
print(dir(module))
```

Eg. print(dir(math)) will list all the functions in the math module